# Can both "running for" and "running to" be used with the present perfect continuous?

Tags: present-perfect-progressive

I have a question about the following sentences, which both refer to a single occasion:

> Why are you out of breath?
>   I have been running for the bus. (uttered when entering the bus)
>
> Why are you out of breath?
>   I have been running to work. (uttered when arriving at work)

I would like to know if both sentences are possible and if this is not the case why not? Is it to do with "running for" being atelic and "running to" being telic?

Comment: `I have been running`, implies you have done it multiple times/ it is continuous. For example someone might say `Wow you've lost weight` to which they might reply `Thanks, I've been running to work`. You would say `I had to run for the bus` if asked why you were out of breath on a single occasion.

Comment: @User112638726 Can I ask if you are American?

Comment: nope, why do you ask?

Comment: Because of your answer. Usage of ppc differs among Americans and Brits. I am not criticising or anything, just interested. Are you British?

Comment: I guessed that.  Does it sound American/British? Do you want to learn American or British English more?

Comment: @User112638726 I would just like to know what nationality you are. What have you "guessed"?

Comment: The tense has nothing to do with for and to.

Comment: What @Lambie said. Perfect and continuous verb forms are completely irrelevant to the choice of preposition in contexts like *I ran **to** the office* and *I ran **for** the bus.*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it pointlessly confuses the matter of ***preposition choice*** with irrelevant variations in verb tenses

Comment: @User112638726 In this example either ***to*** or ***for*** could be used for a single instance or when talking about multiple occasions. Any suggestion that one applies to a single case and the other to many is misleading. Both prepositions are available in either case.

Comment: @WS2 I wasn't answering the actual question, which is why it is a comment, just pointing out that both are incorrect for a single occasion as running is a continuous/ongoing verb.

Comment: @WS2 Do you agree that "I've been running" can be used for a single instance of running?

Comment: @anouk Yes, of course it can.

Answer (score 0):

The [Briish Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/present-perfect-simple-and-continuous) english web site offers this explanation of present perfect:

> We use both the present perfect simple (have or has + past participle) and the present perfect continuous (have or has + been + -ing form) to talk about past actions or states which **are still connected** to the present.

Note the highlighted text. if you ran for the bus, or to work, you probably stopped when you got there, so there is no connection to the present. You would have a connection to the present if you have been running to work every day, and you intend to do so tomorrow as well. In your examples, there is no connection to the the present, so you use simple past (indicating that you probably ran all of the way) or [past continuous](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/past-continuous) (indicating that you probably ran at least part, but not all, of the way):

> I ran for the bus. - *simple past*
>   I was running for the bus. - *past continuous*
>
> I ran to work. - *simple past*
>   I was running to work. - *past continuous*

Comment: @JavaLatteThe connection to the present is that I am out of breath now. Why are you out of breath? I have been running.

Comment: @anouk: That's interesting: if you leave off "for the bus" or "to work", PPC is acceptable. Maybe specifying the destination/objective is like specifying an endpoint: if there is an endpoint, we prefer simple past/past continuous.

Comment: I have found loads of examples stating: "I have been running for the bus" that is why I am confused.

Comment: I disagree with this (it may be an American/British thing).  PPC is perfectly appropriate because, as @anouk correctly points out, it is in response to a question about the present ("why are you out of breath?"), so the answer is describing his *present condition* as being a condition that resulted from running for the bus.  PC would also work, but that doesn't prohibit the use of PPC.  "have been running to work" I think is also technically OK, but is more likely to be interpreted by a listener as a habitual act, rather than a single instance connected to the present.

Comment: @Foogod "I am out of breath because I have been running for the bus" can be used for a single instance in your opinion?

Comment: @anouk Yes, I think that's perfectly fine and natural.  *present perfect continuous* makes sense there because you are talking about your *present condition* and saying that it is due to your *past activity*.