# Is there a difference in telicity between "to run for the bus" and "to run to the bus station"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

I would like to know if there is a difference in telicity:

1. > to run for the bus
2. > to run to the bus station

I am asking because "to run to the bus station" is telic, because there is definite endpoint. I feel "to run for the bus" is different, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Bus station is two words.

Comment: Very few native English speakers will know what 'telicity' is.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that's what wikipedia is for :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telicity

Answer (score 1):

You are right that, when you run to the bus station, you are running to a particular place.

When you run for the bus, you are running **to** the bus stop, with the intention of getting there in time to catch the bus. We therefore use **for** in the sense of "having a purpose of" catching the bus.

Note that the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for) also offers this meaning for  **for**, though it's not about an endpoint but a general direction:

> **for preposition (TOWARDS)**
>
> **towards; in the direction of**:
>   They looked as if they were heading for the train station.
>   Just follow signs for the museum.
>   This time tomorrow we'll be setting off for the States.
>   It says this train is for (= going to stop at) Birmingham and Coventry only

Comment: Is it possible to say "I have been running to the bus station" to explain why I am panting and sweating? Because it is possible with "I have been running for the bus".

Comment: If you are still panting and sweating, it is likely you are at the bus station now, and it would be clumsy to say "to the bus station". You could say something like "I have been running to get here".

Comment: @anouk, I don't think that present perfect is OK in this sentence, but comments aren't the right place to explain. Why don't you ask a question about it?

Comment: @ JavaLatte I did, but the question wasn't answered: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/241591/can-both-running-for-and-running-to-be-used-with-the-present-perfect-continu  I would really appreciate an explanation.

Comment: @Michael Harvey If I am at the bus station now I am no longer running, the running has stopped, right?

Comment: @anouk - what do you think?

Comment: @anouk I have answered your question

Comment: @Michael Harvey I think it has stopped.

Comment: You used the phrase "no longer" in your comment-question. What do you think that means?

Comment: @Michael Harvey My question is "I have been running to get here" means I am not running now. Is that correct?

Comment: It does not always mean that. The Present Perfect Continuous tense (I have been ...ing) is about activity that started in the past and still continues to the present or very immediate past.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Yes, but in my example " I am panting because I have been running to get here" the running has stopped in the immediate past, because I am here now.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. Other example: I have been drilling holes in the wall, but they are all done now.

Answer (score 0):

From the Wikipedia article on telicity:

> One common way to gauge whether an English verb phrase is telic is to see whether such a phrase as in an hour, in the sense of "within an hour", (known as a time-frame adverbial) can be applied to it.
>
> Other phrases can be tested similarly; for example, walked home is telic, because "John walked home in an hour" is fine, while "John walked home for an hour" is bad, and walked around is atelic, because "John walked around in an hour" is bad, while "John walked around for an hour" is fine.

Both of these work, so both are telic.

> to run for the bus in an hour
>
> to run to the bus in an hour

The reason why they both work is more due to context than anything else.

*For X* identifies the reason of your running action, and *to X* identifies the target of your running action.

There are phrases like *run for the hills* -- the verb *run* lets *for X* carries the implication of *to X*.  This is not necessarily true for other verbs of motion - *walk for the bus* will sound like you want to take a walk to make the bus happy or something similar, not walk to the bus.